# How much sugar and corn starch is in commercial icing sugar?

Tags: sugar, ratio

If anyone knows about the percentages of sugar & corn starch to make icing sugar for commercial purposes, please let me know. How important is it for these percentages to be accurate?

Comment: Check out this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-kN7aCVGz0

Comment: Since the OP never returned, I'm editing the title to match the body of the question, and adding in what I think was meant by the title.

Answer (score 1):

Powdered sugar (as it is known in the US) is approximately 3% cornstarch by weight.

See, for example, [United Sugar's](http://www.unitedsugars.com/productsPowderedSugar.html) website.  This is typical of all manufactuers, however.

Comment: I tweaked the question slightly, if you want to add anything about how important it is to make it with exactly 3% cornstarch.